# Create the maximum possible array in matlab

Tags: matlab

My PC has three RAMs (8GB, 4GB, 4GB). The memory command says that the maximum size for an array is 2045MB the same as before installing the two 4GB RAMs , I want to overcome the 2045 limitation by usage of ram space. my question is how to create the maximum possible array with my system? I use win8.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the type of the array. A `double` takes 8 bytes in Matlab - but a `int8` takes just one. When you want "maximum possible" are you talking about number of elements, or space occupied in memory? See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91711 for a table showing how large arrays can be. By the way - are you sure it says `2045` and not `2047`?

Comment: Number of elements for a double array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91711:

> To calculate the size of the array that the 'Maximum Possible array' output of MEMORY command corresponds to, simple divide by the number of bytes required by each of the array elements.

So in your case, the size of the array is

```
A = zeros(1, floor(2045*1024*1024 / 8);
```

That is a one dimensional array with the number of elements that exactly fills 2045 MB

Comment: Ok, but i want to overcome the 2045 limitation by usage of more ram space

Comment: If you read the link I sent you, the limit is a consequence of the way that Matlab and the operating system interact. Change your version of the operating system, or change your version of Matlab. That is the conclusion you can draw from the table at the link and the associated text.

Comment: Ok, i will use 64bit win with 64 matlab